# Pure Python with Cython decorators: How to get attribute access at module level

Tags: python, cython

I would like to write some Pure Python with Cython decorator, but when I rename my NONE.PY to NONE.PYX I've got an error.
To workaround this issue I need to wrap each attribute with a pure python definition call without decorator.
I wonder why...

here the module none.pyx (if you rename it to none.py, you will have no issue at all)

```
import cython

@cython.cfunc
@cython.returns(cython.double)
@cython.locals(n=cython.int,i=cython.int,r=cython.int)
def ccrange(n):
  r=0
  for i in range(n):
    r+=i
  return r

def crange(n):  return ccrange(n)
```

and the python test file test_none.py:

```
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
import none
n=10000
print ">>pure python call>>",none.crange(n)
print ">>cython call>>",none.ccrange(n)
```

Result with none.pyx:

> > pure python call>> 49995000.0
> >     cython call>>
> >     Traceback (most recent call last):
> >     File "C:\Users\damien\python4d\bacoland\test_none.py", line 6, in 
> >        print ">>cython call>>",none.ccrange(n)
> >     AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ccrange'

Rename none.pyx to none.py, give:

> > pure python call>> 49995000
> >     cython call>> 49995000

Thanks for Help! Have a NiceDay :-)

EDIT:
Avoid the decorator @cython.cfunc is breaking the speed avantage of cython...
Consider this following code with and without @cython.cfunc:

```
@cython.cfunc
@cython.returns(cython.double)
@cython.locals(n=cython.int)
def fibo_c(n):
  if n == 0 or n == 1:
      return n
  return fibo_c(n-2) + fibo_c(n-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

`@cython.cfunc` decorator is an equivalent to `cdef`ing a function (see [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/pure.html?highlight=cfunc#extension-types-and-cdef-functions) for details), so this function is accessible only within `C` code. So, to make it accessible from Python get rid of `@cython.cfunc`.

Comment: ok, but i loose the speed interest of cython...
how can I make a pure python with cython decorators to optimize for speed my code...

Comment: That depends on your code... The code from the example is too simple to get any speed increase just wrapping it into cython because you already have large overhead of calling a function from external library. If you want to call functions from C and python (latter with large python overheads), you can use `cpdef`.

Comment: Thanks Andrey. The key point, here, is to use same file without change any line between interprete version (.py) and (.pyx). For fibo example (see my edit part of my question), you can find a huge speed different between with and without @cython.func decorator; and use of cpdef is not pure python...

Comment: Then, I guess it's not possible with state-of-the-art cython, unless you make a feature request for `@cython.cpfunc` decorator (or write such a decorator yourself). The difference in speed you observed with `fibo` is due to recursive nature of the function - with `cfunc` all the recursive calls are made in C way, which is way faster than python.

Answer (score 2):

You should replace your `@cython.cfunc` (equivalent of `cdef`, ie. only callable from C) by `@cython.ccall` (equivalent of `cpdef`, ie. both accessible using slow Python calling convention and fast C calling convention).